# VBA Excel array writing all values as 0 in cells

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2007

I have the below code:

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()    

    Dim uniqueID As Integer
    uniqueID = 0

    Dim notInOrder As Boolean
    notInOrder = False

    Dim inOrder As Boolean
    inOrder = False

    Dim employeeNumber As String

    Dim week As Integer

    Dim tdate As Date
    tdate = Now

    Dim qtyWelds As Integer
    qtyWelds = 26


    Dim totalOfWeldsInOrder As Integer
    totalOfWeldsInOrder = 0


    Dim qtyGridsInspected As Integer
    qtyGridsInspected = 1

    Dim s1 As Integer
    Dim s2 As Integer
    Dim s3 As Integer
    Dim s4 As Integer
    Dim s5 As Integer
    Dim s6 As Integer
    Dim s7 As Integer
    Dim s8 As Integer
    Dim s9 As Integer
    Dim s10 As Integer
    Dim s11 As Integer
    Dim s12 As Integer
    Dim s13 As Integer
    Dim s14 As Integer
    Dim s15 As Integer
    Dim s16 As Integer
    Dim s17 As Integer
    Dim s18 As Integer
    Dim s19 As Integer
    Dim s20 As Integer
    Dim s21 As Integer
    Dim s22 As Integer
    Dim s23 As Integer
    Dim s24 As Integer
    Dim s25 As Integer
    Dim s26 As Integer

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Shapes("cBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0 Then
        totalOfWeldsInOrder = totalOfWeldsInOrder + 1
        s1 = 0
        notInOrder = True
    End If

        .....


    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Shapes("cBox26").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0 Then
        totalOfWeldsInOrder = totalOfWeldsInOrder + 1
        s26 = 0
        notInOrder = True
    End If

    Dim sInOrder As Integer

    If inOrder = True Then
        sInOrder = 1
    Else
        sInOder = 0
    End If


    Dim snotInOrder As Integer

    If notInOrder = True Then
        snotInOrder = 1
    Else
        snotInOrder = 0
    End If

    Dim rowArray(1 To 35) As String


    uniqueID = GetLastRow() - 1


    rowArray(1) = uniqueID

        .....

    rowArray(35) = s26


    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = GetLastRow()

    Debug.Print "Last Row: ", lastRow

    InsertRow lastRow, rowArray


End Sub
Public Function GetLastRow() As Long

    Dim wbshtSelect         As Worksheet
    Dim LR_wbSelectNew      As Long

    Set wbshtSelect = Sheets("Data")

    ' find last row with data in Column AI9 at current regioun starting at cell AI9
    With wbshtSelect.Range("AI9").CurrentRegion
        LR_wbSelectNew = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With

    Dim rng         As Range
    Set rng = wbshtSelect.Range("AI9:AI" & LR_wbSelectNew)

    ' find last row inside the range, ignore values inside formulas
    LR_wbSelectNew = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("AI9"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row

    GetLastRow = LR_wbSelectNew

End Function

Function InsertRow(lastRow As Long, List() As String)

    Dim newRow As Range
    Dim rowArray As Variant

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")


    rowArray = List()

    lastRow = lastRow + 1

        For Each c In wsData.Range("A" & lastRow & ":AI" & lastRow)
                For Each s In rowArray
                    c.Value = s
                Next s
        Next c

    Debug.Print "New Row: ", lastRow

End Function
```

I have a button and when I click the Button the macro runs the above code. The code will get the last filled row, and insert data from an array (in code) in the next row. The array is getting populated correctly, however when it comes to writing it to cell all values are returned as 0.

I tried converting the values using `CStr(variable)` with no success (still saved as 0).

The function that writes values to row:

```
Function InsertRow(lastRow As Long, List() As String)

    Dim newRow As Range
    Dim rowArray As Variant

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")


    rowArray = List()

    lastRow = lastRow + 1

        For Each c In wsData.Range("A" & lastRow & ":AI" & lastRow)
                For Each s In rowArray
                    c.Value = s
                Next s
        Next c

    Debug.Print "New Row: ", lastRow

End Function
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

***NOTE1: I am using Office 2007 (Excel)***

***NOTE2: I have removed some of the repetitive code.*** (denoted as .... in code)

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything - that is probably an issue. Btw your code could be appreciably shortened if you used arrays and a loop.

Comment: The function is not supposed to return anything, it just insert rows with values given in the parameters. Yeah, I will shorten code once I have a finishid working script.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I wanted to write an array to a range. The below is what worked:

```
Function InsertRow(lastRow As Long, List() As String)

    Dim newRow As Range
    Dim rowArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")

    rowArray = List()

    lastRow = lastRow + 1


    wsData.Range("A" & lastRow & ":AI" & lastRow) = rowArray

    Debug.Print "New Row: ", lastRow

End Function
```